# Adding AsyncAppender to log4j.properties

Tags: java, xml, logging, asynchronous, log4j

I am trying to add AsyncLogger to log4j.properties. I have found examples of adding AsyncLogger to lo4j.xml file, but not to log4j.properties. Can you please let me know how to add it. Please provide a sample log4j.properties entry for AsyncLogger.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't AsyncAppenders need to be configured by code or XML

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering my question. Can you help with another question of mine regarding Async Logger. The link for question is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691897/how-to-test-if-log4js-async-logger-is-logging-aynchronously